# How can I represent and operate on time values greater than 24:00 in Java?

Tags: java, time, java-time

I'm currently doing some work in an application domain that uses time values greater than 24:00 to represent times after midnight that are still associated with the previous day's details.  For instance, it might use 25:15 on Monday to represent 1:15 AM on Tuesday, since from a domain standpoint, this value is still associated with Monday's data.

This type of time usage is briefly mentioned in the Wikipedia article for the [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Times_after_24:00):

> Time-of-day notations beyond 24:00 (such as 24:01 or 25:00 instead of 00:01 or 01:00) are not commonly used and not covered by the relevant standards. However, they have been used occasionally in some special contexts in [various countries] where business hours extend beyond midnight, such as broadcast television production and scheduling.

Java provides the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) model class to represent times.  However, `LocalTime` is constrained to be between midnight of the given day (inclusive) and midnight the next day (exclusive), i.e. in the range `[0:00-23:59:59.999999999]`.

The Java Time API was written to be flexible, but with more specialized concepts excluded from the core API.  As mentioned in the [ThreeTen Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project curated by the primary author of the Java 8 date & time library:

> Not every piece of date/time logic is destined for the JDK. Some concepts are too specialized or too bulky to make it in.

I have not had luck finding an existing type or other straightforward way to model this less-constrained time type through the core Java libraries or [ThreeTen Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/).  It is however, very possible that I'm missing something, perhaps something fairly obvious.

How can I model this sort of less-constrained time in Java, ideally using the `java.time` API or an extension thereof a la the ThreeTen-Extra project?  I would like to be able to use it to textually represent the time value ("25:15") and ideally perform temporal calculations with it (e.g. convert "Monday @ 25:15" to "Tuesday @ 1:15 AM").

If there isn't a straightforward approach, I'll probably end up opening an issue at the Threeten-Extra project.

Comment: I clearly see the need. I was once developing a bus time table system. We had our own home-grown class for a time of day from 0:00 to 36:00 with 1 minute precision because night buses are usually planned as part of the time table for the previous day (I never saw it used for time beyond 4 AM (28:00), but rather make the range too big than too small). Obviously we had functionality for printing as ordinary times. When a bus leaves at 23:58 and arrives at the next stop at 0:03, the time table user needs no further explanation, they understand. Only internally we needed to distinguish.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought is to store that as a [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object. You could easily use the getters on that class to construct the `HH:mm` string when you want to display the value, or use something like the Apache Commons [DurationFormatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DurationFormatUtils.html).

The `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` classes support operations like adding and subtracting Durations.

Answer (score 3):

### No that does not exist

I am convinced that no class in the three-ten family or commonly used class from elsewhere supports what you want. The closest my search could get was the `DayCycles` class of the Time4J library (link at the bottom). It consists of a time of day (a `PlainTime`) and a count of days relative to an unspecified date, so what you ask for; but it’s specifically for returning the result of adding or subtracting time from a `PlainTime` and doesn’t offer any functionality of its own.

### Spin your own

I wouldn’t think that developing your own class that could interoperate with java.time would be too hard. Likely base it off `java.time.Duration` as Mark B suggests, depending on more precise requirements.

Parsing and formatting may be the hardest part if you have demanding requirements for these. Possibly it’s worth taking inspiration from the source code for the Joda-Time library since this includes facilities for formatting and parsing durations.

Another source of inspiration would be the source of `java.time.LocalTime`.

Here are the very first few bits:

```
public class SpecializedTime {

    private Duration timeSince0000;
    
    private SpecializedTime(Duration timeSince0000) {
        this.timeSince0000 = timeSince0000;
    }

    static SpecializedTime parse(String text, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
        ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
        TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parseUnresolved(text, position);
        if (position.getErrorIndex() != -1) {
            throw new DateTimeParseException("Parse error", text, position.getErrorIndex());
        }
        if (position.getIndex() != text.length()) {
            throw new DateTimeParseException("Unparsed text", text, position.getIndex());
        }
        if (! parsed.isSupported(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
            throw new DateTimeParseException("Cannot resolve", text, 0);
        }
        
        Duration time = Duration.ofHours(parsed.getLong(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        if (parsed.isSupported(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR)) {
            int minuteOfHour = parsed.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR);
            // Should validate, 0..59
            time = time.plusMinutes(minuteOfHour);
        }
        // Same for seconds and nanoseconds
        
        return new SpecializedTime(time);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", timeSince0000.toHours(), timeSince0000.toMinutesPart());
    }

}
```

Demonstration:

```
        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m");
        SpecializedTime st = SpecializedTime.parse("25:15", timeFormatter);
        System.out.println(st);
```

Output:

> 25:15

### Link

[Documentation of `DayCycles`](http://www.time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/DayCycles.html) form Time4J

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a type which directly models this concept in ThreeTen-Extra or in the core Java libraries.  However, a feature request now exists in ThreeTen-Extra requesting this functionality ([threeten-extra#169](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/issues/169)).

ThreeTen-Extra project maintainer Stephen Colebourne [has commented](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/issues/169#issuecomment-759729525) that this would be a sensible addition to the library, so it's seems to be mostly a matter of when or whether anybody steps up to implement the feature.

Stephen Colebourne also suggested a few ways of implementing this feature within the library.  One of these suggested approaches could be used as part of a custom solution to this problem.

> It could be a combination of `LocalTime` and a number of days, or something closer to `LocalTime`. Various design options.